# use laravel passport for make token and send request with axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, token, laravel-passport

i want make panel . . for frontend i use vuejs ...

I have 3 ways

1 -- i use laravel default auth with make:auth and  use

```
enter code here
       \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,

enter code here
```

middleware for Make Auto Token and send my  axios request ,,

2 -  i use laravel default auth with make:auth and  make login.vue and send login request with axios for laravel  default auth service and in authenticated method in AuthenticatesUsers class 
use this code and return token for login.vue ..

```
enter code here
    $http = new Client();

        $response = $http->post(config('app.url') . '/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ],
        ]); 
enter code here
```

after get token in login vue set this in vuex  and set in header and send axiox request with token

3 -- i just use laravel passport and send user name and password for passport , make token and return token .. and send request with axios and token ..

Which way is safer?
Which is the best choice?

if i use 2 or 3  save token in localstorage or cookie? tanks